# Android - catch backspace (delete) button on custom EditText

Tags: android, input, android-edittext

I want to catch the backspace/delete button event in soft keyboard on `EditText` custom.

How can I do it ?

I tried these solutions but they do not work for me :

[Android custom EditText and back button override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965961/android-custom-edittext-and-back-button-override)

[EditText OnKeyDown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305972/edittext-onkeydown)

[Get back key event on EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113437/get-back-key-event-on-edittext)

[Android EditText delete(backspace) key event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886858/android-edittext-deletebackspace-key-event/11377462#11377462)

Thanks for your help !

---

**EDIT :**
I found a fix for that isssue with the function DispatchKeyEvent :

```
@Override public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(@NonNull KeyEvent event) { 
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
        && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
     // ... 
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "do not work"? Where are you testing? In an emulator or on a device?

Comment: When I pressed any button in the soft keyboard, the code in the function is not executed (outside of all conditions). I tested with my device (Samsung galaxy S5).

Comment: Checking the docs for the [KeyEvent class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html), it states catching soft input is unreliable. You may have better luck overriding `onBackPressed()` in your `Activity` class and doing what you need to do in there. **Edit:** Unless of course you mean "move cursor one space back" kind of back press rather than the standard back navigation key.

Comment: @PPartisan onBackPressed will not be helpful when soft input is open

Comment: @PPartisan  I want the standard back button for deleting a character in my edittext, but with my rules

Comment: @nolimitee, please take a look at a solution I provided below (http://stackoverflow.com/a/34858233/1808829).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a fix for that isssue with the function DispatchKeyEvent :

```
@Override public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(@NonNull KeyEvent event) { 
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
        && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
        // ... 
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: It will work only for default edittext not for Custom edittext.

Answer (score 0):

Catching Key Events from soft input methods in Android is unreliable. Here is an excerpt from the JavaDoc for the `KeyEvent` class:

> As soft input methods can use multiple and inventive ways of inputting
>   text, there is no guarantee that any key press on a soft keyboard will
>   generate a key event: this is left to the IME's discretion, and in
>   fact sending such events is discouraged. You should never rely on
>   receiving KeyEvents for any key on a soft input method. In particular,
>   the default software keyboard will never send any key event to any
>   application targetting Jelly Bean or later, and will only send events
>   for some presses of the delete and return keys to applications
>   targetting Ice Cream Sandwich or earlier.

One workaround could involve using `TextWatcher`. Whenever a delete occurs in an `EditText`, the character count drops.

```
myEditText.addTextChangedListener(this);
//...
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    if (count == 0) {
        //text was deleted. 
    }
}
```

**Edit:** This is untested, so may not be completely reliable. In addition, it's worth pointing out that `count` may also read `0` if a long section of text is selected and then replaced. I created a library once that was designed to add Undo/Redo functionality to `EditText`, but can also [`identify the difference between text being replaced and deleted`](https://github.com/PPartisan/RunDo), so this may be of use to you if you require more accuracy.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but i retried with the dispatchKeyEvent function and it worked !

Comment: @nolimitee Good :) - it may be worth answering your own question in case it helps anyone else in future with this problem

Comment: @nolimitee, please post the solution as an answer, it will be helpful for the rest...

Answer (score 0):

Please, take a look at a solution I provided in another similar topic: [Android - cannot capture backspace/delete press in soft. keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34857618/1808829). You need to build your custom `EditText` class and override `onCreateInputConnection` method in it. It will give you access to `deleteSurroundingText` event which is firing when you click backspace. I've tested it in some devices and hope it will work in others also. Try it and give a feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go..

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            private int before;
            private int after;
            private int prevLength;
            private boolean isBackPressed;
            ArrayList<Integer> arrayList;

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                prevLength = charSequence.length();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int end, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                isBackPressed = prevLength > editable.length();

                if(isBackPressed){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Back",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```